# Algorithm to rank markets

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, statistics

I have a dataset that contains information about markets. The dataset contains the following: Volume of market, # of purchases, avg purchases across all days, avg purchases across all days and across all markets, and the avg percentage of how cheaper this market is compared to all the markets.

The data looks something like this:

```
market volume  numPurchases   transDate  avgDailyPurchases  AvgDailyPurchasesAll  
JFK    500     32             20190102   50                 75
JFK    500     60             20190103   50                 75
ATL    450     40             20190102   40                 75

avgPercentCheaperThanAll
.22
.22
.75
```

What I'd like to do is rank the markets. A top market is defined where `avgDailyPurhcases` is high relative to its volume and `avgPercentCheaperThanAll` is also high. So in the data above, ATL would be a better market than JFK even though JFK has more `avgDailyPurchases`, ATL is much cheaper than all the markets.

I tried using the IMDB formula where they rank movies, but instead I used my own representation of the variables for example:

```
weighted rating (WR) = (v ÷ (v+m)) × R + (m ÷ (v+m)) × C 
v = volume of market
m = minimum volume required to be in the list
R = avgDailyPurchases
C = AvgDailyPurchasesAll
```

This gives me an almost good list, but it is missing one major factor: The avgPercentCheaperThanAll. How can I add this into the equation to get better results?

Comment: Disclaimer: just thinking out loud.

Your formulla is equivalent to (1+ (m/v) (R + C) I would try a normalization like so ((X-max-Xmin)/(X-max+X-min)) >> finally, 

(1+ (m/v) (R + C) * ((X-max-Xmin)/(X-max+X-min)) where X is avgPercentCheaperThanAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points that should be considered before designing the rating equation or any equation would be.

1. **Identify the input variables**: As could be understood it could be.

   > avgDailyPurhcases, AvgDailyPurchasesAll,  avgPercentCheaperThanAll,
   >   volume, a minimum threshold for volume
2. **Normalize the input variables**: From the above data, it can be inferred that volume runs in 100's, average daily purchases in 10's while your cheaper variable runs in decimals. If you try to use these variables in a single equation directly without normalizing then your rating will be biased and driven primarily by *volume* factor. Therefore you should consider normalizing them, use this link to learn about more [Normalize Data](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/normalized/).
3. **Assign weights**: You want ***avgPercentCheaperThanAll*** to have higher preference than ***avgDailyPurchases***  variable, this would be achieved by assigning appropriate weights to the variables.
4. **Define the relationships**: You should consider defining relationships between your variables whether they are directly related or indirectly related for your rating.
5. **Deriving the equation**: The final step would be to derive to the equation. From the above step, this would be very easy just combine all relationships then you will be left with an equation of type:

   > Rating = [weight of variable 1]*[normalized variable 1 value] + .... so on.

You will be able to derive your required equation from the above steps and that equation would be more clear to you and more adapt to your situation. Otherwise, you can copy any rating equation on the web and modify it according to your need but each equation will give different results and you won't be able to control them when more input variables arrive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would I know what the value of the weights should be?

Comment: Depends on the requirements, suppose you figure out that avgPercentCheaperThanAll is twice as significant than all your factors combined then assign 0.5 to it and distribute remaining 0.5 to other factors it simply depends on the requirements.